# Printing from Visual Studio 2017 throws error "PrintTicket provider failed to convert PrintTicket to DEVMODE."

Tags: visual-studio, printing, visual-studio-2017

I have never been able to print from Visual Studio 2017 Professional. (15.9.5)

Whenever I try to print I get the following error:

> PrintTicket provider failed to convert PrintTicket to DEVMODE. 
>   Win 32 error: -2147221164

I have no printing related extensions enabled or even installed. MS web site has shown others with this problem but there is never any solutions proposed.

Anyone have any ideas of what to try?

Comment: What print function are you invoking? Are you talking about printing from the IDE, within a program, from an ASPX-hosted webform, etc...???

Comment: From the IDE.  Just trying to print a page of code from the editor.

Comment: Can you print from Notepad to the same print-dialog destination printer? Can you print from any other version of Visual Studio (you list Visual Studio, generic, as a question tag)? Is the printer an actual printer? Is this IDE instance running in a virtual machine?